# how to show an entire row of a searched result excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, search, worksheet

```
CINorRC = InputBox("Entrez un CIN ou RC correct.")
If StrPtr(CINorRC) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf CINorRC = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Err...")
End If

    With Me.SearchDisplayX
    .AddItem
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = "CIN/RC"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "ART"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Nom"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Nature"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = "LI"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = "**"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = "DP"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = "OBS"
    End With

If Trim(CINorRC) <> "" Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws.Range("A2:L999")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=CINorRC, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Application.Goto Rng, True
    Me.SearchDisplayX.AddItem Rng.rows
    End If
    End With
    Next ws
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End If
```

Here is the whole code

the listbox name SearchDispaly is showing only the CINorRC value rather than the entirerow that has the value in its first cell

and if you see other code problems i would appreciate it to help me with them <3

Comment: Maybe use find next method.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Offset` method get the entire row as:

```
 If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Me.SearchDisplayX.AddItem Rng.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 8).Value           
 End If
```

Comment: thanks for the effort dude but an error "application-defined or an object-defined error" appeared